# count image hash(md5) in adobe air

Tags: image, hash, air, adobe, md5

1. I use HTML+JAVASCRITP+CSS develop desktop software in adobe air platform
2. I download md5.js that count md5 value as same php md5 value
3. air.filestream function read location of file and send to md5.js to count hash ,normal file(js,php,css,txt) can count as same php md5 value, but count image file get wrroy hash,the image isn't change.

```
var fileStream = new air.FileStream(); 
var target = new air.File(file.nativePath); 
fileStream.open(target , air.FileMode.READ);
var str = fileStream.readMultiByte(target.size,'utf-8'); alert(window.md5(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [this library](http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/) that does reading binary data.
Then, unzip the swc and get the swf file to a lib folder in your app path.

You must check the xml file to get the qualified name of the md5 function you want to use
(.by.blooddy.crypto.MD5.hashBytes(data) )

Add an script include line on the html header

```
<script src="lib/library.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></script>
```

and you can use the function trought the window.runtime object:

```
hash = window.runtime.by.blooddy.crypto.MD5.hashBytes(data);
```

and this hash will be the same you can get with a md5 in php.

By the way you must read the file using readBytes instead of readMultiByte.

adobe link ([Using ActionScript libraries within an HTML page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ed9.html))

Comment: I think air very trouble,I dont use it fovever

Comment: I want to mention that blooddy's MD5 crashes on AIR 16 and 17